# Add data attribute to Drupal Views image

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-views

I have a view that prints title, body and image fields. Now I want to be able to print a data attribute to image markup. At the moment it produces the following HTML:

```
<img width="578" height="472" src="http://mydomain.com/sites/mydomain.com/files/image-small.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image">
```

But I want to provide the URL of a bigger image as a data attribute. Like this:

```
<img width="578" height="472" src="http://mydomain.com/sites/mydomain.com/files/image-small.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image" data-big-image="http://mydomain.com/sites/mydomain.com/files/image-big.jpg" />
```

How can achieve this? Can I do it inside views or do I neeed to make changes to view template?

Answer (score 0):

Any easy way to get access to whole load of data is to add a node id field in the views ui then in your template file before the loop you can enter the following:

```
  $nid = strip_tags($fields['nid']->content);
  $node = node_load($nid);
```

Do a var_dump() of the $node to see what data you can play with.

For example, getting your image path would be something similar to the following:

```
$node->field_cl_image['und'][0]['uri']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it completely in Views UI using [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) fields.

You'll want to add both large and small image fields first, then exclude them from display, so you can easily refer to them using the $data object later.

Add a PHP field, leave the 'value code' empty. In the 'output code', simply construct the HTML you want:

```
<?php
print '<img src="' . $data->field_your_small_image_field['some']['array'] .
 '" data-big-image="' . $data->field_your_big_image_field['some']['array'] . '" />';
?>`
```

Do a `dsm($data);` (with [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) enabled) in the output code area to find the exact array keys to the URL.